# Xcode Debugger: Why is it only showing me assembler?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, debugging

I'm just starting out with Cocoa development in Xcode, doing the hello world example. I'm up to step 6 of the section "[runtime debugging](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/A_Tour_of_Xcode/020-Xcode_Workflow_Tutorial/qt_projects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000890-CH205-TPXREF133)", which is

> Using the Step Over button in the debugger toolbar, begin stepping through the code. As each line of code executes, you can examine the program’s state. The value of a variable is sometimes drawn in red to indicate that the value was modified in the last step.
>   Notice that the debugger pauses before executing the indicated line. After each pause, you can add additional breakpoints or choose Debug > Restart to terminate the application and start a new debugging session.

now what I've been pulling my hair out for over the last hour is the fact that this debugger will only show me assembly code. I can manually select my source code file, but as soon as I click "Step over" I'm right back in assembler view. I can't for the life of me figure out how to turn the assembler off, and make it show me my source code!

Answer (score 149, accepted):

I know this article is a hundred years old, but in case anyone is wondering how to address this issue in more recent Xcode versions (as opposed to Xcode 3), you'll find the appropriate setting labeled *Always Show Disassembly* under **Debug>Debug Workflow** in Xcode 6 and up. Ensure the option is **NOT** checked.

This was driving me crazy, too.

*NOTE: The information above is still valid for Xcode 15+. I've applied updates to this answer as new versions of Xcode have been released. Fortunately, the option has remained unchanged since Xcode 6 (so far).*

In Xcode 5, the option was labeled *Show Disassembly When Debugging* under **Debug>Debug Workflow**. Ensure that "Show Disassembly When Debugging" is unchecked.

Back in Xcode 4, the *Show Disassembly When Debugging* setting was found under **Product>Debug Workflow**. Again, ensure that the option remains unchecked.

Comment: How would this setting look like in Xcode 4.4? I have unchecked the option "Show Disassembly When Debugging", but still get the assembler window.

Comment: Should be the same, but note that the conditions @PeterHosey mentions above remain true, too. Make sure you're viewing your source code, and that debug symbols are not stripped.

Comment: what about XCode6? it is now "Always show Disassembly", it's unchecked on my end and it's going too deep.

Comment: @AndreiG. What do you mean by "going too deep?" Does the setting not seem to work the same as in the past?

Comment: @VeryVito Unchecking "Always Show Disassembly" does not prevent the debugger from showing the disassembly in Xcode 6.1. I have to assume this is a bug.

Comment: Has anyone been able to find a way to prevent the debugger from showing disassembly in Xcode 6.1? When I run my code and I step into or step over at the end of a block of code it always takes me to the assembly even when I don't have Always Show Disassembly unmarked. Is there an explicit mark to Never Show Disassembly?

Comment: @jacks4jokers and woz: I'm not seeing the same behavior (to be fair, I'm using 6.1.1 now). Without being able to replicate, I can only suggest reviewing the symbol-stripping settings within a given target's Build Settings. Sounds like debug symbols are being stripped somewhere along the way.

Comment: @VeryVito Thank you! You saved me some hair

Comment: "Hundred years old". Got it!

Comment: This helped Debug Workflow -> Alway Show Disassembly

Answer (score 11):

There are two other things to make sure of:

1. That you're looking at one of your own functions/methods. If the stack frame you're looking at is a function or method from one of the frameworks, you're going to see assembly no matter how you have Xcode configured.
2. That you are running a Debug build. Strip debug symbols (as in a Release build), and you'll be looking at assembly even for your own code, no matter what.

Comment: Didn't solve my problem, but interesting info... thanks

Answer (score 2):

I actually figured this out before I posted, but I wanted to save others potential future headaches, (and also in case I forget later) as I could not find the answer to this by searching stack overflow, but I did find that [I'm not alone.](http://www.mac-forums.com/forums/os-x-darwin-development/106125-xcode-debugging-source-code.html)

From the run menu, select "Debugger Display" > "Source Only", or "Debugger Display" > "Source and Disassembly"

Answer (score 0):

refer @Mike Fahy, summary to:

- Logic

  - `Xcode`->`Debug`->`Debug Workflow`->`Always Show Disassembly`

    - Selected == Show assembly code

      - [image: show asm selected]
    - Unselected == Not show assembly code == show source code (ObjC/Swift/...)

      - [image: show asm not selected]
- for you: **Unselect** `Always Show Disassembly`