# Xcode debugger - debug through methods

Tags: xcode, debugging

I'm used to using Visual Studio's debugger which will essentially track the logic path through the application, jumping from method to method allowing you to see how something might not be working.

When I'm debugging in Xcode (4.6.3) using 'Step into' or 'step over' as needs be I go through some methods but then it seems to jump into compiled code and I'm lost. I can't see the logic flow or order of events due to this so is there something I'm doing wrong?

How can I track what's actually being done in the code but in a way that makes sense and doesn't show me compiled code?

For instance I put a breakpoint on ViewDidLoad as I want to see what happens after that method is called because my app isn't working as expected. Break points elsewhere aren't getting hit so there's a problem which I need to track down.

So my ViewDidLoad breakpoint is hit, I work my way through that method and then when the debugger hits the end of the method it flies off into compiled code so I don't know what's next in the order of events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can avoid this issue, given the code it "flies off" to likely has no symbols and anyway you don't have the source.

This situation is not unique to Xcode; it will happen with Visual Studio and every other O/S.

One approach is to provide all the subclassed methods of the view/whatever (even if all they do is call the `[super method]` and nothing more) and set breakpoints on each of them.

Alternatively if instance variables are getting whacked in unexpected ways, set a [watchpoint](http://lldb.llvm.org/tutorial.html).

Comment: I suppose what I mean is that in VS I find is that there's a logic flow. Method A calls Method B which in turn calls Method C and the results are shown. So when you're debugging you can follow that flow with the debugger. In Xcode I'm finding that Method A runs and then just ends, I'm trying to see what happens next but can't, yet I know something is.

Comment: @FullTimeSkeleton Hmmm, I don't see how Xcode could be different to VS in this manner; it might be the nature of Cocoa (Touch) compared to Windows I guess, but fundamentally the nature of the code is the same.

Comment: I dunno, maybe it's just the way I'm used to coding (I'm debugging someone else's code in Xcode). In VS I generally know that my Page_Load method will maybe call a method that populates a repeater and so on. In this code I know there's a tableview that is being populated but the debugger isn't showing me where. I guess I'll figure it out.

Comment: @FullTimeSkeleton You will want to find the datasource and delegate of the tableview and break on its methods.

Comment: What if I don't know what the logic flow is and would like to see the flow of execution; say i'm looking at the code for the first time. Do you mean to say this can't be done in xcode?

For example, if I put a breakpoint randomly in a method (M2) and this method is being called from another method (M1) (AND I DON'T KNOW THIS). So after the last line in M2, the IDE just goes to compiled code and not to M1. But I need to go to M1 to know the flow.

Get it? Is this possible in Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the exact same situation. However, the below two links helped me understand why it was happening.

Basically, you first need to "*UN-CHECK*" the option in **DEBUG->DEBUG WORKFLOW->SHOW DISASSEMBLY WHEN DEBUGGING**.

Then, If you're trying to debug your own code, then debugging works the same way as in Visual Studio. But if the code that you're looking is being called from some Framework, then the debugger will surely go back to assembly code no matter what the setting of "Show Disassembly" is.

Check these links for further clarity. They are answers from the same page.

[XCode Debugger: Why is it only showing me assembler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421093/xcode-debugger-why-is-it-only-showing-me-assembler?rq=1)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1421275/2377928
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7301489/2377928

Thanks,

Hope this helps!