# How to stop Xcode 6 from displaying disassembly when running the debugger

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

When I am running the Xcode 6 debugger, every time I reach the end of a function and I step into or step over the last statement Xcode takes me to the disassembly of the function. All I want to see is to return to my code and continue, rather than view the disassembly.

In my project explicitly when I step into at the end of the function.
The same happens when I step over as well.

[image: regular function]

[image: disassembly]

In this answer it can be seen that the Always Show Disassembly being unchecked does not necessarily mean that the disassembly will not show, so is there an explicit way to state to Never Show Disassembly? Or is this merely a bug in Xcode 6?

[XCode Debugger: Why is it only showing me assembler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421093/xcode-debugger-why-is-it-only-showing-me-assembler)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode is showing you the assembly because that's the **only** thing it has available to show you. If you don't want to look at it, ignore it.

If you step into the last statement, you're stepping into the implementation of `[NSArray count]` (or whatever `self.photos` is); if you step over it, your method exits, and you're now looking at the function in `UITableView` that calls your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method. Both of these methods are in Apple's frameworks, so there's no source code available.

Turning off "Always Show Disassembly" doesn't mean that you'll never see assembler code. It just means that Xcode will show you source code when possible. There is no "Never Show Disassembly" option because that would leave Xcode with *nothing* to display in some situations.

Comment: "If you don't want to look at it, ignore it."   That's like saying "If you don't like the way it feels when I punch you in the face ignore it". You can't just ignore it when there's lines upon lines of assembly code.

Comment: @Marin Like I said in my answer -- what do you expect Xcode to display instead? You're looking at the internals of a method that you don't have source code for.

Comment: I think it should just stop there.

Comment: As pointed out, there is no source code for the proprietary elements used in iOS/macOS applications. Hence, Xcode does not have anything to display. I use "Continue" when I hit assembly code with some other breakpoints set at appropriate places (this is the best I can do with a closed source API)