# Xcode 11 breakpoints stop only on HEX code

Tags: xcode, breakpoints, xcode11, symbolicate

I have just updated to Xcode 11 and going crazy with the debugger. I am trying to simple thing of stopping at a breakpoint and stepping trough my code.

I can add the breakpoint without problem, but when the debugger stops there, is shows me a file with HEX code only. I can inspect variables, but cannot step trough the code. See screen
shot. Do I have something wrong in my settings?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode Debugger: Why is it only showing me assembler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421093/xcode-debugger-why-is-it-only-showing-me-assembler)

Answer (score 2):

Xcode > Debug > Debug Workflow > always show disassembly (non check)

reference site

[Xcode Debugger: Why is it only showing me assembler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421093/xcode-debugger-why-is-it-only-showing-me-assembler)